# Add html attribute to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending some html to a div using jQuery, where both `rowString` and `inputString` are defined previously:

```
$("#filterContainer").append(
            rowString +
            `<label class='filterLabel' for=${filter}>${filter}</label>` +
            "<i class='fas fa-minus-circle removeFilter float-right'></i>" +
            inputString +
            "</div>"
        );
```

`rowString` looks like this:

```
let rowString = "<input id='autocomplete' type='search' class='form-control' name='filters[location]' >"
```

And I am trying to inject a value into this. I've tried `rowString.val('myvalue')`, but it fails with `Uncaught TypeError: string.val is not a function`.

How can I add an html attribute such as `value` to a string?

Comment: Your `rowString` is just a string but your `rowString.val(...)` only works on jQuery objects.  Create a jQuery object for it like Taplar does in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(rowString).attr('value', 'myvalue').prop('outerHTML')
```

You can parse it, set the value, and then get the outerHTML to get the HTML back.

```js
let rowString = "<input id='autocomplete' type='search' class='form-control' name='filters[location]' >";

console.log(
  $(rowString).attr('value', 'myvalue').prop('outerHTML')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I do `$(rowString).val('myval').val()` I get `myval` which is great. When I use `$(rowString).val('myval').prop('outerHTML')` I get the original string back (with no value)

Comment: Sorry, you actually have to use `attr()` in this case.  Answer updated. @fugu

Answer (score 0):

```
$(rowString).val('myvalue')
```

And, change your append to this:

```
$("#filterContainer").append(`${rowString}<label class='filterLabel' for=${filter}>${filter}</label><i class='fas fa-minus-circle removeFilter float-right'></i>${inputString}</div>`);
```